# PowerShell Script to Get a Directory Total Size

Tags: windows, filesystems, scripting, powershell

I need to get the size of a directory, recursively. I have to do this every month or so. I want to make a powershell script to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809014/powershell-script-to-get-a-directory-total-size) and I get this excellent answer:

```
function Get-DirectorySize() {
  param ([string]$root = $(resolve-path .))
  gci -re $root |
    ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    measure-object -sum -property Length
}
```

This actually produces a bit of a summary object which will include the count of items. You can just grab the Sum property though and that will be the sum of the lengths.

```
$sum = (Get-DirectorySize "Some\File\Path").Sum
```

Thanks to [JaredPad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/125842-directory-size-using-powershell.html) out.